# Select one word, then have all matching words automatically select?

Tags: select, automation, notepad++

I have been working in Notepad++ recently, and last night, spent at least an hour manually selecting many of the same phrase with Ctrl+Select.  I needed to select all occurrences of 'yyty' (Just a phrase so I could easily find it), but could not see or find a quick way to do that.  I ended up just using the Ctr+Select method, but when doing this 80 times, it gets quite annoying.  I need something that will allow me to select a word, then have all matching words become selected (NOT highlighted or marked, as I need to be able to run the column editor tool on the selection to auto-number all of the selections) automatically (by automatically, I mean after clicking something to run the auto-selector).  I am willing to install a plugin for NP++ if needed.

Comment: In SynWrite u can do it: call Find, enter string, check option "Select results", press "Mark all" -- to place multi-selections on all.

Comment: Thanks for showing me SynWrite and what you have told me is working, but is there some what that I can take the selection that I just made, and replace all selected objects with a numbered list from 0 to 9, where 0 goes into the first selection, and 9 goes into the tenth selection, and the selections between the first and last increment by one?  (Sorry if this is confusing, if you can't understand what I mean, I will edit in an example)

Comment: It not possible simply, but is possible via Python API, if u enter N lines in Py Console panel (need to read API).